# Python for - reference to last element

Tags: python

Let's say I have this code:

```
fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for field in fields:
    d.pop(field)
    d.append(field - 1) # Incorrect
```

In the incorrect line, if we are in the second iteration ('b'), how to reference to the last one ('a')?

Comment: Can you provide more information on you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `enumerate`

```
for i,field in enumerate(fields):
  d.pop(field)
  if i > 0:
    d.append(fields[i-1])
```

Comment: This of course fails in the first iteration, because fields has no index `-1`

Comment: @Jieter Edited. The OP will obviously have to handle that. It's not very clear what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, if you want to iterate over a list in this fashion, your can use:

```
for i in range(len(fields)):
    d.pop(fields[i])
    d.append(fields[i-1])
```

And obviously, you have to think about what behaviour you want for the first loop.

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can use `enumerate` which is a better alternative. `range(len(list))` is not the pythonic way.